# Norms defined on multi variable polynomial space

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question. Is there any example of norms defined on multi variables polynomial space? I know the Lp norm defined on one variable polynomial space. Is there any analogue in multi variable case? Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

To define an "$L^p$-norm", we simply need a basis for our vector space.

More precisely, if $V$ is a vector space with basis $\mathcal{B}$ (possibly infinite), we define a $L^p$-norm by setting
$$\Vert \lambda_1b_1+\cdots+\lambda_nb_n\Vert_p=\left(\sum |\lambda_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$$
where $\lambda_i$ are in the field, and the $b_i$ are distinct elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

In the case of one-variable polynomials, we are using the canonical basis $1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots$.

In the case of multi-variable polynomials, say with variables $x_1,x_2,\ldots$, you can use bases of the form $x_{i_1}^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_{i_k}^{\alpha_k}$, where $i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k$ and $\alpha_j\geq 1$.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!